# Expand Categorical x-axis in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I can't figure out how to use `expand()` within `scale_x_discrete()` to expand a categorical x-axis so that placing a label to the right of points won't be off of the plot.

I know that if x was numeric, I could simply adjust the max limit of x so that the points all shift to the left. However, I cannot figure out how to do this with a categorical variable.  I don't even care if the expanded variable label is "". I just need more space to the right of the last categorical variable on the x axis.

Here is example data that could be used to illustrate how to successfully do this:

```
data(iris)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = iris, aes(x = Species, y = Sepal.Width)) +
  geom_jitter()
```

Thanks for any and all help, and please don't hesitate to ask any clarification questions!

EDIT: Plot for easy visual explanation

[image]

Comment: can you provide an example of your desired output, I'm not quite following your explanation.

Comment: @CyrusMohammadian Yup. [Here](https://i.gyazo.com/ff4a7c18af77f67f90b78faa536c25a4.png) is a crude example of what I'm talking about. "FakeT" is supposed to read "Fake Text", but the X axis isn't allowing it to show and I can't figure out how to expand it because it is a categorical x variable, rather than numeric.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could just append a blank level to the existing levels of your categorical variable, as in:

```
data(iris)

levels(iris$Species) <- c(levels(iris$Species),'') # add blank level

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = iris, aes(x = Species, y = Sepal.Width)) +
  geom_jitter() +
  scale_x_discrete(drop=FALSE) # don't drop unused blank level
```

[image]

**Update:** Or, if you really want to extend the x axis by a numeric value then you could first convert the categorical to numeric via `as.integer()`:

```
data(iris)
specVals <- levels(iris$Species)
iris$Species <- as.integer(iris$Species)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = iris, aes(x = Species, y = Sepal.Width)) +
  geom_jitter(height=0) + # on 2nd thought -- don't add noise to the quantitative axis
  scale_x_continuous(limits=c(min(iris$Species)-0.5,max(iris$Species)+1),
                     breaks=(min(iris$Species)):(max(iris$Species)+1), 
                     labels=c(specVals,''))
```

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I was asking for. 

One follow up question: Does this mean that I couldn't arbitrarily extend the x-axis by a numerical value and I only can extend it by the value of a blank categorical level?

Comment: @medavis6 also doable, see ?xlim or scale_x_continuous(limits= )

Comment: Right, but is that kind of stuff possible in this situation with categorical variables? I'm genuinely asking that question.

Comment: @medavis6  You can expand axes via `expand` in `scale_x_discrete`, but this expands the axis in both directions (so, e.g., not just on the right of the plot).

Comment: @medavis6 you would have to convert the categorical to numeric first -- see update to answer

Comment: Yes, this was the simple answer that I could not see myself. Thank you @C8H10N4O2. Dummy coding is the solution I need.

Answer (score 9):

Since I'm facing the same problem... I found `expand_limits(...)` quite useful here:

```
dat <- data.frame(x= c('a', 'b', 'c'), y= 1:3)
ggplot(data= dat, aes(x= x, y= y)) + 
    geom_point() + 
    expand_limits(x= c(-1, 5))
```

Or, to avoid hardcoding the limits:

```
    expand_limits(x= c(-1, length(levels(dat$x)) + 2))
```

(With `ggplot2_3.1.0`)
[image]

Comment: do you know if it's possible to expand the x-limits without having an additional x-tick-mark showing up? Specifically, I'd like to add more x-axis space on the right of the graph (where the x-axis is a date range), but not have the last date-label show up.