# Custom spacing between ticks on discrete axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am creating a plot where i have a discrete y-axis and a continuous x-axis.  I want to create the impression of grouping by moving some y-axis ticks closer together and increase the space between the groups. I tried to demonstrate it by whipping something up in paint.

```
ggplot(data = mpg, aes(y = trans, x = displ, group = 1)) + geom_step()
```

[image]

So what I'm trying to do is move the `manual(mx)`, the `auto(sx)`, the `auto(lx)` closer together (blue arrows) and increase the space between these groups (red arrows)

My idea was to create empty ticks between the groups, but ggplot is ignoring those:

```
brks <- mpg$trans %>% unique() %>% sort()
brks <- append(brks, "test", 2)
brks <- append(brks, "", 5)

ggplot(data = mpg, aes(y = trans, x = displ, group = 1)) + geom_step() +
  scale_y_discrete(breaks = brks)
```

Does anybody have an idea how to achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: It sounds to me that you want to add some visual distinction for your groups. Have you considered creating a grouping variable and adding facetting using `facet_wrap(grouping_variable, ncol=1)` to achieve that?

Comment: Otherwise check this solution for adding empty factor levels https://stackoverflow.com/a/39880532/6086135

Comment: facetting was not an option, but I got what I want from your suggested answer. Thanks!